# Best method to give access to "Answers" (eg Bookmarks)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search, roles

I have a *non-admin* SharePoint user who needs to be able to add Bookmarks in Microsoft search so that they apply globally.

What is the best way to give the user access to settings like **/Adminportal/Home#/MicrosoftSearch/bookmarks** (or even **/_layouts/15/searchadmin/TA_SearchAdministration.aspx**) so that they can make timely adjustments to search.

This is a governance question about how to make the tools accessible to users who understand the business.

I have reviewed roles and permissions and it seems like these are tied to the global admin role. Is this only possible through a custom application that interacts with the Graph?

Answer (score 1):

The roles are not documented in the [list of admin roles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/about-admin-roles?view=o365-worldwide), but setting up a search editor is [described here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/setup-microsoft-search#step-2-assign-search-admin-and-search-editor). If you are unable to find it in the [list of roles in the admin portal](https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home?#/rbac/directory), you my need to click "Show all roles" at the bottom of the list.

[image: list of admin roles filtered to search related roles]